# Running a standard receptacle on GFCI line

Tags: receptacle, gfci, refrigerator

I am recently done with my kitchen renovation. I have L shaped kitchen where the smaller portion has refrigerator on it. The refrigerator has been moved from from the corner of the wall to the center, covered by cabinet frame. The refrigerator used to run from an outlet under the countertop line, it was not protected by gfci. Where as above counter lines is protected by gfci, where my refrigerator is connected now in the middle of the wall. As refrigerator has higher loads at times, gfci trips very often.

I am very novice at this but I am wondering if it is possible to jump just this receptacle which is used to connect refrigerator so that it is not protected by the gfci but still maintaining rest of the receptacles over the counter protected by gfci? If yes, how?

Thanks a ton in advance,

- Bimal

Comment: Do you have access to run additional cable/wires?

Comment: I could but it would go around the refrigerator, would kill the beauty of the kitchen :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be higher load levels but a problem with GFCI's and motor loads, my state exemption for GFCI's includes refrigerator and freezers. If the refrigerator is the first outlet in your kitchen small appliance branch circuit a GFCI outlet can be added to the next outlet and be legal with NEC2014 code. I am out of town and do not have my code book but there is an exhibit showing the refrigerator as the 1st outlet and the rest as GFCI protected on 1 of the 2 small appliance circuits required. I like the refrigerator on its own circuit but it is code to put it first or last on one of the 2 required 20a circuits,,, if not first expect to loose a lot of food, In my professional opinion.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I have a starting gfci outlet and then 2nd one in the line is the refrigerator. I am still going to use the first gfci outlet for small kitchen appliances. Would it be still OK to start gfci from the 3rd outlet? Also, I don't have any issues with any small appliances on gfci line, it's just this refrigerator.

Comment: You can have the first GFCI outlet and feed the frig from the line side of the GFCI then on the 3rd add a new GFCI. This way all the other outlets will be protected and the fridg won't be tripping the GFCI.

Comment: Yes, that will solve the issue. Thank you Ed.

Comment: By the way, is there any document or reference guide for how to have a regular outlet after an GFCI? Is it just about changing wires?